# Qt Call Member Function of QDialog Inherited Class

Tags: c++, qt

I've got two classes. The first, class B, is declared:

```
B::B(QWidget * parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
}

B::B(A * aClass, C * cClass)
{
    setupUi(this);

    connect(m_checkbox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), A, SLOT(toggleAClass(bool)));    
}

void B::setBChecked(bool checked)
{
    m_checkbox->setChecked(checked);
}
```

And a class A, which has the code:

```
B * m_b = new B(this, m_c);
```

and further down calls:

```
m_b->B::setBChecked(true);

// I also tried
// m_b->setBChecked(true);
```

The issue I'm having, is that since `B` is a QDialog, it's saying 
`'B' is not a base of 'QDialog'`

I need to be able to call custom functions of the `B` class from the `A` class.

Any help is appreciated~

Comment: The error you're getting doesn't appear to be possible with the code you've shown.  Please provide a [MCVE].  What error do you get with just `m_b->setBChecked(true)`?

Comment: The error with just `m_b->setBChecked(true);` yeilds `'class QDialog' has no member named 'setBChecked'`

I'll try and add more to the example

Comment: I found the issue and posted an answer of how I fixed it. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The issue was foud in `A.hh`. I had declared

```
QDialog * m_b;
```

So everything referencing `m_b` was going off of the QDialog class.

Changing this to

```
class B;
B * m_b;
```

Fixed the issue.